# Update duplicate columns their foreign key - mysql

Tags: mysql

I have a table with products: a foreign key(fk id), name and more data. 
 There are duplicates in name, but there are for example customers related to the fk id 
Therefore I want to update the duplicates with the first matching fk id

Example:

```
fk id   name
1       abc
2       abc
3       abc
67      abc
```

**Table after update:**

```
fk id       name

1           abc

1           abc

1           abc

1           abc
```

So far I got a query to put them together in a comma separated list, but I am missing the Update:

```
SELECT 
count(*) as amount, 
group_concat(name) as names, 
group_concat(id) as ids 
FROM db.product 
GROUP BY name 
HAVING amount> 1;
```

Comment: By first matching id do you mean the lowest of all ids for the same name?

Comment: yes, first matching id for each name

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In mysql you can use [joins in update statements](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/update.html). I would create a subquery that returns the lowest id (min()) for each name that appears multiple times. Since in mysql you cannot select from the same table that is being updated, therefore an extra layer of subselect is added on the top of the subselect:

```
UPDATE db.product
INNER JOIN (SELECT * FROM 
(SELECT name, min(id) as minid
FROM db.product 
GROUP BY name 
HAVING count(*)> 1) t2 ) t on t.name=db.product.name
SET db.product.id=t.minid;
```